# warning: could not load any Objective-C class information in Swift realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm currently developing new project with swift and XCode version is 7.2. Problem is Realm error is recently coming up and I don't know why.

Please help me how to do?

> Version 1.0.1 of Realm is now available:
>   https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/v1.0.1/CHANGELOG.md warning:
>   could not load any Objective-C class information. This will
>   significantly reduce the quality of type information available. (lldb)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you enable NSZombies as [explained in answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode) and try to reproduce the issue? It can provide significant help in debugging memory management issues, which when they happen in other places in your app could also lead to random crashes at completely unrelated places.

---

The logs message, you see, are very likely not related to the crash as seen in the provided screenshot.

> warning: could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available. (lldb)

The message on the second line is coming from LLDB and tries to explain that its functionality is restricted due to some problem. It can help to clean the build folder and build from scratch.

You can achieve that by holding down the Option key <kbd>⌥</kbd> and select *Product* > *Clean Builder Folder…* in the Xcode menu. (<kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>)